# Create matrix with numpy from a function in vectorized fashion?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Suppose I have two arrays `x` and `t` of length `N` and I want to create a matrix, where

```
M_i,j = t_i * t_j * func(x_i, x_j)
```

In this case `func()` simply takes in two elements of `x` and returns a scalar value.

```
t.shape = (N, )
x.shape = (N, 2)

// expected
M.shape = (N, N)
```

Question is: Can this be done without looping through the whole matrix in a vectorized fashion using numpy? I know there are ways to populate matrizes via functions, the problem is, that here the function arguments depend on the indices of the matrix which has me stuck.

Comment: It depends on `func`. If `func` can broadcast its arguments, it should be just `M = t[:, np.newaxis] * t * func(x[:, np.newaxis], x)` (or maybe slightly more efficient with `M = np.einsum('i,j,ij->ij', t, t, func(x[:, np.newaxis], x))`).

Comment: @jdehesa yes, I already found a solution for my particular function as described in my answer. But I guess it can't be done in general..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the shortest way to do but it's possible

```
> np.diag(t) @ np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: x[i] + x[j], (2, 2), dtype=int) @ np.diag(t)

array([[ 0, 15],
       [15, 50]])
```

the function is defined as a simple lambda, substitute with your own.
here I used

```
> t=np.array([3,5])
> x=np.array([0,1])
```

Comment: I still have some error here, as the middle term returns a scalar in my case. Here is my implementation (func() should calculate a rbf-kernel):
`np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: np.exp((-np.linalg.norm(x[i] - x[j]) ** 2) / (2 * self.sigma ** 2)), (x.shape[0], x.shape[0]), dtype=int)`

Comment: you're applying `norm` to scalar quantity, I think that's the reason it doesn't work.  Since you're squaring you don't even need absolute value.

Comment: each element of `x` is a `(2, )` array, so this should still be correct, as the difference between two elements is also a vector...I take the norm of the vector and then square the skalar result.

Comment: OK, I used x as a 1D array in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in this particular case I was able to answer my own question, since my function that originally takes two inputs actually just computes their differences and then calculates further values with that result.

With that in mind I was able to create a "Matrix of Differences" and use standard numpy functions in a vectorized manner as follows (by breaking up my function into its components):

Original Function (RBF Kernel):

```
def CalculateGaussKernel(self, x1minusx2):
    return np.exp((-np.linalg.norm(x1minusx2) ** 2) / (2 * self.sigma ** 2))
```

Code that calculates Formular from OP in vectorized manner:

```
t_outer = np.outer(t, t)
DiffMat = x.reshape(-1, 1, 2) - x
KernelMat = np.exp(-(np.linalg.norm(DiffMat, axis=2)**2) / (2 * self.sigma**2))
K = np.multiply(t_outer, KernelMat)
```

As mentioned, this works only due to the nature of my specific function. @karakfa provided another answer for general function, however I couldn't make it work so far. Anyway, maybe his answer is better suitable for my question.